# Git Use of uninitialized value $branchName in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

Commands used for Git tag and push

```
node('buidl1') {
    stage('stage1') {
        sshagent (credentials: ['buser']) {
            sh """
                git tag -l
                rm -f .git/hooks/*
                git tag td5.6.7.8 -m "Adding 5.6.7.8"
                cd ${WORKSPACE} 
                git remote set-url origin git@gitrepo1:Sandbox/SandRepo
                git push origin td5.6.7.8
             """
        }
    } 
}
```

Error:

```
remote: Use of uninitialized value $BRANCH_NAME in concatenation (.) or string at /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/Sandbox/SandRepo.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive line 132, <STDIN> line 1.
```

I have reviewed, $BRANCH_NAME  was not invoke or used in the project code. Do you know the reason for referring  BRANCH_NAME from prereceive hooks & get rid of the uninitialized warning from the jenkins console?

Comment: You were given `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/Sandbox/SandRepo.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive line 132` information in the error message. Have you checked that `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/Sandbox/SandRepo.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive line 132` and tried to find out what happens there and why BRANCH_NAME is not set as it apparently should? What's this Sandbox repo? who has written its pre-receive? is it yours or someone's else work? If not yours, have you considered simply getting rid of it?

Comment: Also, it feels somewhat weird to use $BRANCH_NAME in pre-receive hook.. I'm no expert in that matter but pre-receive hook is called while handling a 'push' and it certainly may be updating **multiple branches** so.. using single simple $BRANCH_NAME in such a script seems suspicious at least